# What did Batman expect Damian to do to take back the "City of Bane"?

Tags: dc, comics, batman

*This contains many spoilers for the "City of Bane" Batman arc (2019); too many to use spoiler blocks without having the whole question hidden behind them.*

Quickly summed up, "City of Bane" has Thomas Wayne (from the "Flashpoint" world) and Bane defeating Batman and ruling over Gotham, Thomas posing as Batman. Naturally, once Batman gets better, him and Catwoman go on to fight back.

However, it's not clear to me what the original plan to take back Gotham from Thomas Wayne and Bane was; and especially not what Damian was supposed to achieve in it. The way it's presented to the reader, there are three key plot points:

- Issue #77 has Damian breaking Thomas Wayne's rule of "no Bat-family member is to intervene in Gotham, or Alfred dies". He takes out Gotham Girl, tries to defeat his grandfather, [gets beaten](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmxV2.jpg), and leads to Alfred's death. So far, this looks like typical Damian arrogance and stubbornness.

  [image: Robin vs Thomas Wayne]
- Issue #79 has Batman telling Catwoman that Alfred signalled he was safe, and that he's therefore ["sending Damian in"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjRcS.png). At this point, the reader is lead to believe Batman has full control of the situation, and Damian's defiance in issue #77 makes more sense; it's also implied that the two stories in the arc, namely Gotham's and Batman/Catwoman's, do not take place at the exact same time.

  [image: Batman and Catwoman on a beach]
- Issue #83 makes it clear-cut for Batman and the reader that [Alfred deliberately lied in telling Batman he was safe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZP4qJ.jpg), when he was not; the point being to stop Alfred from being an obstacle to Batman taking back Gotham.

  [image: record of Alfred's voice]

This last bullet implies that when "sending Damian in", Batman was triggering some kind of plan to end the City of Bane, now that he did not have to worry about Alfred anymore. **But what was that original plan, and how was Damian alone supposed to manage anything?**

Damian was sent alone to... do what exactly? Sure, he removed the threat Gotham Girl posed, but what after that? No other Bat-family showed up for anything, so I'm guessing Batman did not put them in motion. What next? Damian is resourceful, but Batman cannot expect him to handle Thomas Wayne and Bane (and other villains) all by himself until he and Catwoman arrive to the rescue.